# Python: Import modules from a sub-repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I need to clone a Python repo inside my project and use it as a library (even if the repo code wasn't thought of as a package). I'd like to do that while minimizing the modification to the cloned code.

My code structure is the following:

```
root/
├── third_party/
│   └── repo/
│       ├── dirA/
│       │   └── fileA.py
│       └── dirB/
│           ├── fileB.py
│           └── utils.py
└── src/
    ├── utils/
    │   └── misc.py
    └── main.py
```

I'm having quite some problems with the import statements. This is an overview of the imports in the different files:

```py
#fileB.py
from dirA.fileA import funcA
from utils import util_func

#main.py
from third_party.repo.dirA.fileA import funcA
from third_party.repo.dirB.fileB import funcB
from utils.misc import misc_func
```

I tested two approaches.

#### Method 1

If I run `python src/main.py` from the project root I'd have to add to the `PYTHONPATH` three directories: `root`, `repo`, and `dirB`. The problem with this is that it causes a conflict with the `import utils` referring to two different targets.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "root/src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils.misc import misc_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.misc'; 'utils' is not a package
```

#### Method 2

I thought the solution was to isolate repo by installing it as a separate package so I did this:

- added an `__init__.py` inside `repo`
- added a `setup.py` in `third_party` and run `python setup.py install`

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='repo', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

- Changed the `main.py` imports to:

```py
from repo.dirA.fileA import funcA
from repo.dirB.fileB import funcB
from utils.misc import misc_func
```

I was convinced this would work but what I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "root/src/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from repo.dirB.fileB import funcB
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/repo-1.0-py3.10.egg/repo/dirB/fileB.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dirA'
```

I thought that in an installed package absolute imports would resolve from the root of the package but apparently not.

I've never delved too much into Python's import system so I'm pretty much ignorant about it. Would anyone know a good solution to making this setup work?

#### MRE

I've uploaded an MRE here: https://github.com/andrearosasco/import-mre

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in how python imports work, but I had to find some solutions myself because I struggled with these types of problems many times. A solution I've found, which might not be the optimal one, is to use relative imports, so your code would like like this:

```py
#main.py
from ..third_party.repo.dirA.fileA import funcA
from ..third_party.repo.dirB.fileB import funcB
from .utils.misc import misc_func


def main():
    return
```

```py
#fileB.py
from ..dirA.fileA import funcA
from .utils import util_func


def funcB():
    return
```

Then you can `cd` in the parent folder of `root` and run your python script with:

```
python -m root.src.main
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I think it technically should work. The thing is that I don't want to modify ```repo/``` too much. While this is only a MWE, in the actual project there are a lot of absolute import statements that I would need to convert inside of ```repo/```

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved with a tool like **Poetry**, using the `pyproject.toml` file to point out the different sources.

Example, using a `pyproject.toml` in the top folder.

```ini
[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    {include = "src"},
    {include = "repo",from = "third_party"}
]
```

Depending on what you want the top namespaces to be, you could set the values for *include* and *from* differently.

**EDIT**, without Poetry or any specific setup:

I looked into your code a little bit more and think that your imports need to be absolute. This should solve it:

(in `main.py`)

```py
from third_party.repo.dirA.fileA import funcA
from third_party.repo.dirB.fileB import funcB
from src.utils.misc import misc_func
```

(in third_party/repo/dirB/fileB.py)

```py
from third_party.repo.dirA.fileA import funcA
from .utils import util_func
```

You should be able to run the code - without the need of Poetry - in this way:

```bash
PYTHONPATH=./ python src/main.py
```

Comment: hey, thanks for answering. I tried that (without including "src" because I don't wanna package my main) but unfortunately, the results are the same as in "Method 2":
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dirA'

Comment: You should include the "src" too, because the "packages" section will tell the runtime where to find your code. If you leave it out, it won't find it and you'll end up in errors as you describe. The "packages" section is not only for packaging code into something.

Comment: I've tried adding src/ back but it didn't fix it. I think it is because the import error is entirely contained inside repo/. The issue is that once repo/ is installed, either with poetry or the setup.py script, the absolute paths in repo/don't resolve with respect to repo/. Which is kind of weird because otherwise how are absolute imports even used inside installed packages then

Comment: I have updated my answer with a non-Poetry solution as an alternative.